# stackview constraints break when adding two views inside with imageview having fixed width and height

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

i have a stackview with an imageview and a label underneath it but when i try to add it into stackview it doesnt appear and apparently all the constraints break.i want the imageview to be fixed width and height and the stackview to equal the width of the label

```
let userView_stackView = UIStackView()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
  super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

  userView_stackView.axis = .vertical
  userView_stackView.alignment = .center
  userView_stackView.spacing = 5
  userView_stackView.addArrangedSubview(user_imageView)
  userView_stackView.addArrangedSubview(user_name)

  self.contentView.addSubview(userView_stackView)
  stackView_constraints()
}

var user_imageView: UIImageView = {
  let imageView = UIImageView()
  let imageViewHeightAndWidth: CGFloat = 60
  let image = UIImage(named: "steve")
  imageView.image = image
  imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
  imageView.clipsToBounds = true
  imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
  imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageViewHeightAndWidth / 2

  imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageViewHeightAndWidth).isActive = true
  imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageViewHeightAndWidth).isActive = true

  return imageView
}()

var user_name: UILabel = {
  let label = UILabel()
  label.text = "Steve Rodriquez"
  label.font = label.font.withSize(14)
  return label
}()

func stackView_constraints() {
  userView_stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive =
    true
  userView_stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
    .isActive = true
  userView_stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0
  ).isActive = true
  userView_stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    .isActive = true
}
```

Adding views like this breaks the constraints and prints the following error on the console where all the constraints are breaking

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d70eb0 UIStackView:0x10327c250.height == 283   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72580 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIStackView:0x10327c250.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d70eb0 UIStackView:0x10327c250.height == 283   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-10-12 10:43:30.597559-0500 Fourmi[1708:291157] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d5f610 UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.width == 60   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72c10 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x10327c250.leading == _UILayoutSpacer:0x281174960'UISV-alignment-spanner'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d73020 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x10327c250.centerX == UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.centerX   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72d50 'UISV-spanning-boundary' _UILayoutSpacer:0x281174960'UISV-alignment-spanner'.leading <= UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72300 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIStackView:0x10327c250.width == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d5f610 UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.width == 60   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-10-12 10:43:30.598068-0500 Fourmi[1708:291157] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d5f5c0 UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.height == 60   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72b70 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x10327c250.top == UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72bc0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UILabel:0x10327e990'Steve Rodriquez']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x10327c250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72c60 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIImageView:0x10327c6d0]-(5)-[UILabel:0x10327e990'Steve Rodriquez']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72580 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIStackView:0x10327c250.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d5f5c0 UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.height == 60   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-10-12 10:43:30.598469-0500 Fourmi[1708:291157] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72b70 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x10327c250.top == UIImageView:0x10327c6d0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72bc0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UILabel:0x10327e990'Steve Rodriquez']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x10327c250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72c60 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIImageView:0x10327c6d0]-(5)-[UILabel:0x10327e990'Steve Rodriquez']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72580 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIStackView:0x10327c250.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d72c60 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIImageView:0x10327c6d0]-(5)-[UILabel:0x10327e990'Steve Rodriquez']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-10-12 10:43:30.598894-0500 Fourmi[1708:291157] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x280d40000 h=--& v=--& UIStackView:0x10327c250.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d5ff20 UIStackView:0x10327c250.width == UITableViewCellContentView:0x10327fdb0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d40370 'fittingSizeHTarget' UITableViewCellContentView:0x10327fdb0.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d5ff20 UIStackView:0x10327c250.width == UITableViewCellContentView:0x10327fdb0.width   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-10-12 10:43:30.599762-0500 Fourmi[1708:291157] [Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead. Cell: <Fourmi.ChatTableViewCell: 0x10327af70; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 375 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x282e41300>>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `userView_stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false`fixed it